AWS athena transponse rows into columns
I have query below
SELECT 
"key",
sum(coalesce(try_cast (sre as double),0)) as sre,
sum(coalesce(try_cast ("lacy" as double),0)) as "lacy",
sum(coalesce(try_cast ("tiry" as double),0)) as "tiry",
sum(coalesce(try_cast ("casu" as double),0)) as "casu",
sum(coalesce(try_cast ("day" as double),0)) as "day"
FROM table1 
group by "key"
having "key" in ('mars','posu','lest','post','cuti','demo')

output is

I need to transpose the output to get like below

I have tried searching for pivot but looks like pivot is not in athena, can someone suggest how can I achieve this.
Thanks

Might help: (un)pivot on Presto · GitHub

@JohnRotenstein, already tried ,but not working as expected

Rather than using a function to transpose the data, you can calculate it in SQL by using an aggregation on CASE, like this:
select
  'lacy' as thing,
  SUM(CASE when key = 'mars' then coalesce(try_cast(lacy as double),0)) as mars,
  SUM(CASE when key = 'posu' then coalesce(try_cast(lacy as double),0)) as posu,
  SUM(CASE when key = 'lest' then coalesce(try_cast(lacy as double),0)) as lest,
  SUM(CASE when key = 'post' then coalesce(try_cast(lacy as double),0)) as post,
  SUM(CASE when key = 'cuti' then coalesce(try_cast(lacy as double),0)) as cuti,
  SUM(CASE when key = 'mars' then coalesce(try_cast(lacy as double),0)) as mars,
from table1
UNION ALL
select
  'sre' as thing,
  SUM(CASE when key = 'mars' then coalesce(try_cast(sre as double),0)) as mars,
  SUM(CASE when key = 'posu' then coalesce(try_cast(sre as double),0)) as posu,
  SUM(CASE when key = 'lest' then coalesce(try_cast(sre as double),0)) as lest,
  SUM(CASE when key = 'post' then coalesce(try_cast(sre as double),0)) as post,
  SUM(CASE when key = 'cuti' then coalesce(try_cast(sre as double),0)) as cuti,
  SUM(CASE when key = 'mars' then coalesce(try_cast(sre as double),0)) as mars,
from table1
UNION ALL
...

Just keep using UNION to add all the rows. Note that the calculation value changes in the try_cast().
